# My buttons onClickListeners aren't working in my Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons with onClickListeners in my fragment activity and they both don't work. My fragment is also situated in a framelayout connected to another activity if that somehow affects the situation. Here is the code for my onCreateView method in my fragment:

```
private Button btnNewNote,btnNewCategory;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    btnNewNote=view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewNote);
    btnNewNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),CreateNotePop.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnNewCategory=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCategory);
    btnNewCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), CreateNewCategory.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or did you check if your btn is null before adding onClickListener. I mean aren't you able to use getView() instead of doing it with an inflater?

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means. The activities don't start? The methods aren't called? Your app crashes? You laptop explodes?

Comment: @dominicoder the on click listener isn't being called

Comment: @SlothCoding I get no exceptions and my button isnt null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Problem**

You are setting your click listeners on one view and returning a different one that is displayed in the UI

```
// Setting listeners on "view" from newly inflated layout
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
btnNewNote=view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewNote);
btnNewNote.setOnClickListener(...)
btnNewCategory=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCategory);
btnNewCategory.setOnClickListener(...)

// Returning brand-spanking new View that has no listeners set
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

**The solution**

Return the view you set the listeners on.

```
// Setting listeners on "view" from newly inflated layout
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
btnNewNote=view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewNote);
btnNewNote.setOnClickListener //
btnNewCategory=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCategory);
btnNewCategory.setOnClickListener

// Returning the view with the listeners set on it
return view;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try defining logic for your views under `onActivityCreated`

That should do the trick

Comment: I tried to put the onclicklisteners in the onActivityCreated but they still won't work. Do I have to initialize the buttons in the onActivityCreated as well?

Answer (score -1):

1. first of all, please add a context of the activity. for this you have to override the onAttach() and inDetach() method, Inside the onAttach() pls define the context ..please refer below code.

   private Button btnNewNote,btnNewCategory;

   private Context mContext;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

   ```
   btnNewNote=view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewNote);

   btnNewNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,CreateNotePop.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnNewCategory=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCategory);

    btnNewCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, CreateNewCategory.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
   ```

   }

   ```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;
    }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

```
@OnClick({R.id.btnNewNote,R.id.btnAddNewCategory })
void click(View View) {
    switch (View.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnNewNote:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.btnAddNewCategory:
               startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class));
            break;
    }


}
```

Try the above code

Comment: theappschef.in is just the entity which gave you the answer